# datatables datatable tools not working when the parent div has the datatables table inside is hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

i am creating a custom accordion and inside the accordion content (the one which do the slide up and slide down) has a table inside (datatables). So obviously, by default the accordion content div (datatables table wrapper) is hidden but once shown the datatables table tools is not working. You can visit this [demo of mine](http://serverstatus.megamitch.ph/test/) and see the real issue, the first section is where the issue in, click the button and the table will be shown. The second section is a working table where the parent div (wrapper of the datatables table) is not hidden.

Any help, clues, ideas, suggestions, recommendations is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: u mean to say when u click on 'show the hidden div' that time hidden div will show and open div 'not a hidden div' will closed

Comment: please see the demo site, the first section is the accordion like thing (where it will slide down and slide up) and the datatables table tools (copy, excel, pdf, csv) is not working and the second section (the one that has a blue border) is a working sample (csv, excel, pdf, copy) is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `fnResizeButtons()` API method, I believe it was [introduced just to solve this problem](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/3783/issue-with-tabletools-2-0-on-hidden-tabs) :

> This is due to the inability of TableTools (or any DOM script) to find
>   the height and width of an element which is hidden.

change your code to :

```
$(".show").click(function(e){
   $(".container").slideToggle();
   var tableTools = TableTools.fnGetInstance('example');
   tableTools.fnResizeButtons();
});
```

Comment: interesting.. but sadly i got this error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fnResizeButtons' of null" any ideas or clues?

Comment: @CodeDemon, have just replicated your entire site - http://serverstatus.megamitch.ph/test/ -  also used jQuery 1.11.1, dataTables 1.10.6, tableTools 2.2.4 - and it works with the hidden table if I do as above. You are doing it exactly as above? You are sure you are not having a typo somewhere, using another id for the hidden table or similar? if `TableTools.fnGetInstance('example')` returns `null` / `undefined`, it indicates that there is no table with the id example.

Answer (score 2):

I've had similar issues with bootstrap tabs and came up with this:

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    var target_id = $(e.target).attr("href");
    var jqTable = $(target_id).find("table");
    var oTableTools = TableTools.fnGetInstance( jqTable[0] );
    if (oTableTools != null && oTableTools.fnResizeRequired()){
        /**
         *  A resize of TableTools' buttons and DataTables' columns is only required on the
         * first visible draw of the table
         */
        jqTable.dataTable().fnAdjustColumnSizing();
        oTableTools.fnResizeButtons();
    }
});
```

I had, however initialised my tables using `DataTable()` rather than `dataTable()` as you are doing. Perhaps change that and try @davidkonrad suggestion again?

Comment: Yes, the official example -> https://www.datatables.net/extensions/tabletools/api#fnResizeButtons so it should  defently work too, besides the flash buttons should be reset even if the table itself not need resizing. Have replicated the entire demo, it works with `DataTable()` too ...

Answer (score 0):

First html dom loads that time plugin didn't get example id because it is hidden.

You need to apply plugin when example id is not hidden.

Something like below

```
    $(".show").click(function(e){

    $(".container").slideToggle();

    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "dom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
        "tableTools": {
            "sSwfPath": "tabletools/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
        }

});

});
```

or make a function and call it whenever u required